# Pass a formula to an xls file using R's xlsx package

Tags: excel, r, formula, xls, xlsx

Here is the code I used.

```
library(xlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook('D:/test.xls') 
sheets <- getSheets(wb) 
sheet <- sheets[['my_sheet']]

addDataFrame(x = ds, sheet = sheet, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, startRow=3, startColumn=1) 

cell.1 <- createCell(rows[1], colIndex=34)[[1,1]]
setCellValue(cell.1, "=A32*B33")
saveWorkbook(wb, 'D:/test.xls')
```

Adding a dataframe worked without a problem. But when opening the xls file, I saw the `text` "=A32*B33" in cell A34 (an extra ENTER needs to be pressed in order for the formula to work). Can you help me enter a formula correctly?

Comment: Do you not just need to hit F9 (calculate on opening the sheet?) I normally do stuff like this via rcom it gives you more control over this kind of stuff.

Comment: I tried the F9 alternative and that did NOT seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used package `xlsx` in the past, and despite great promise, found it severely lacking in functionality and ease of use. When I searched the package manual a minute ago, it doesn't seem possible to do what you want to do.

The good news is there is **an alternative** in the form of package `XLConnect`. `XLConnect` uses the same Java code (from the Apache POI project) as `xlsx`, so you still have the same high level of interoperability between operating systems.

`XLConnect` has a function that does what you need: `setCellFormula()`.

References:

- The package manual at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf
- Also, I highly recommend the **excellent** vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf

---

PS. Can you tell I like this package?

Comment: I would also say that I like it, if you tell me how can I pass a formula using the R1C1 reference style. The formula I gave was "RC[-27]*(RC[-1]+RC[-3]+RC[-5])" and I got the Error: FormulaParseException (Java): Specified named range 'RC' does not exist in the current workbook.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following

```
cell.1$setCellFormula("A32*B33")
```

instead of

```
setCellValue(cell.1, "=A32*B33")
```

Answer (score -3):

Another Alternative method is output the csv file instead of xls, and then open it with excel.